# php: order of posted variables in array is backard

Tags: php, html, post

Somehow when I submit this form the values are stored last name then first name. How can I change the order?

```
<form action="..posted" method="post" id="register-form">
    <div class=register-form-div>
        First Name: <input class=register-form-input type="text" name="register[First   name]" />
    </div>
    <div class=register-form-div>
        Last Name: <input class=register-form-input type="text" name="register[Last Name]" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="register-submit" name="register-submit" value="Create Account" />
</form>
```

Comment: Does the order it is submitted matter? Sort it on the server.

Answer (score 0):

try that

```
<form action="..posted" method="post" id="register-form">
    <div class=register-form-div>
        First Name: <input class=register-form-input type="text" name="register[1][First   name]" />
    </div>
    <div class=register-form-div>
        Last Name: <input class=register-form-input type="text" name="register[0][Last Name]" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="register-submit" name="register-submit" value="Create Account" />
</form>
```